# Shiny app: downloadHandler does not produce a file

Tags: r, shiny

I can't figure out what's going on - everything seems to work but my app does not generate a file - although it looks like it does.
I run it in Windows, on RStudio 0.98.125, and I run it using the line:
runApp()
Below is a very simple reproducible example:

#### my 'ui.R':

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("My App"),

  sidebarPanel(
    numericInput('NumRuns','Number of runs',value=3,min=3,max=10,step=1),

    actionButton(inputId="goButton","Run!"),

    textInput("downloadData","Save My Data Frame:",value="Data Frame 1"),
    downloadButton('downloadData','Save my file!')

  ),

  mainPanel(
    tabPanel("Some Text",
             h4(textOutput("caption2")),
             tableOutput("mydf"),
             value=3))
  ))
```

#### my 'server.R':

```
shinyServer(function(input,output){

  # Creating files for download at the end

  myout = reactive({
    if(input$goButton==0) return(NULL)

      nrruns=input$NumRuns
      mylist=NULL
      for(i in 1:nrruns){
        mylist[[i]]<-data.frame(a=rnorm(10),b=runif(10))
        names(mylist)[i]<-paste("dataframe",i,sep="")
      }
      return(mylist)
  })

     output$mydf <- renderTable({
     if(input$goButton==0) return(NULL)
     input$goButton
     isolate(
       myout()$dataframe1
     )
   })

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { paste(input$downloadData, " ",Sys.Date(),".csv",sep="") },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(myout()$dataframe1,file,row.names=F)
    }
  )

})
```

Comment: Please don't cross post and if you do have the courtesy to link to your cross post.

Answer (score 61):

Note the download button does not work in the RStudio viewer. Your 
friend might be using the RStudio viewer to view the app. If that is 
the case, please open the app in the external web browser (there is a 
drop-down list on the right of the "Run App" button: Run in Window, 
Run in Viewer Pane, Run External; choose the last one).

Comment: It took me way too long figuring this out, thanks m)

Comment: This is still a thing (Jan 2017)! A file will download, but the result from filename=function() is not used by the RStudio viewer to save the file (at least not in Linux).

Comment: Now it's december 2018 and I ended up here after 2 hours of looking for what went wrong downloading my file! This answer should be at the top.

Comment: October 2020, still a thing!

Answer (score 13):

The example provided works fine for downloading CSV in my tests (if it is from the webbrowser that is, using Run app within RStudio did cause same issue)

Note that if you keep getting something like "download.html" from your download button instead of the downloaded content, you must make sure the ID from downloadButton("myIdHere", ...) matches output$myIdHere = downloadHandler("output.csv", ...)

Also note that if you are using shiny modules (you probably would know if you are using this), then you want to use downloadButton(ns("myIdHere"),...) and then you still have output$myIdHere

Answer (score -4):

Adding to what Colin D said. It can just be that your idNAME is too long.

I just tested on my app that THIS WORKS:

```
     output$download_mastergroup <- downloadHandler(...)   #server side
     downloadButton('download_mastergroup ', 'Download overview') #ui side
```

and that THIS DOES NOT WORK:

```
     output$download_mastergroup_overview <- downloadHandler(...)   #server side
     downloadButton('download_mastergroup_overview ', 'Download overview') #ui side
```

So, be concise and it will be allright!