# Produce csv file using downloadHandler in Shiny

Tags: r, csv, shiny, igraph

Does anyone know how to save the data from the my data frame then export to csv file in the same folder location where the user inputs the file.

Here's my program structure:

1. User will be prompt for folder location then read Pajek(.net) file
2. Calculate the degree of each vertex which is sorted by the degree of each vertex, highest degree is at the top and lowest at the bottom.then show in a data frame.
3. Output a CSV file in the same folder location,

Here's what I've done so far:

ui.R

```
library(igraph)
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=-1)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Finding most influential vertex in a network"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      fileInput("graph", label = h4("Pajek file")),

      downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")


    ),
    mainPanel( uiOutput("tb")             
               )                        
  )
))
```

server.R

```
library(igraph)
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=-1) 

shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {

    filedata <- reactive({
      inFile = input$graph
      if (!is.null(inFile))
      read.graph(file=inFile$datapath, format="pajek")

    })

    Data <- reactive({

      df <- filedata()
      vorder <-order(degree(df), decreasing=TRUE)
      DF <- data.frame(ID=as.numeric(V(df)[vorder]), degree=degree(df)[vorder])

    })

    output$tb <- renderUI({
      if(is.null(filedata()))
      h2("Please select Pajek file..")
    else
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 
                  tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("view")) ) 

    }      
      )
    output$view <- renderTable({

      Data()

    })

       output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

       filename = function() {
        paste("degree", '.csv', sep='')
      },


      content = function(file) {

      write.csv(Data(), file)
      }
    )
    })
```

However, the file did not save.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: do you run your app on browser? `runApp(..., launch.browser = T)`

Comment: Yes i did @AndriyTkachenko

Comment: works for me with [this file](http://vw.indiana.edu/tutorials/pajek/pajek_input.txt). Runnig App on Google Chrome

Comment: Yeah it works on browser but it doesn't work on the app in RStudio @AndriyTkachenko

Comment: So it's about RStudio Viewer limitations. If your app is destinated to users, why do u need a viewer? why not in browser?

Comment: So that the user can save the file at any file location.  @AndriyTkachenko

Comment: See also [another topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984138/shiny-app-downloadhandler-does-not-produce-a-file) on this forum