# Download Handler with reactive datatable (R Shiny)

Tags: r, dataframe, download, shiny, shiny-server

I have simplified a lot the shiny app I'm trying to build, but, in the idea, I have two functions :

```
choose_input <- function(n1,n2,n3){
x1 <<- n1+n2
x2 <<- n2+n3
x3 <<- (n1*n2)/n3
}

createmydata <- function(n){
 c1 <- c(1:n)
 c2 <- c1+(x2*x3)
 c3 <- c2+x1

 df <- data.frame("column1"=c1,"column2"=c2,"column3"=c3)

 return(df)
}
```

You'll tell me that I can do simply one function with these two because they are very simple, but in my app there are a lot of lines and I have to separate the two. Anyway, here is my simulated code :

```
ui <- fluidPage(
 numericInput("n1",label="Choose the first parameter",min=0,max=100,value=3),
 numericInput("n2",label="Choose the second parameter",min=0,max=100,value=4),
 numericInput("n3",label="Choose the third parameter",min=0,max=100,value=5),
 numericInput("n",label="Choose dataframe length",min=1,max=10000,value=100),
radioButtons("filetype", "File type:",
           choices = c("csv", "tsv")),
downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download'),
tableOutput("data")
)

server <- function(input,output){
  RE <- reactive({
  choose_input(input$n1,input$n2,input$n3)
  createmydata(input$n)
   })

 output$data <- renderTable({
RE()
 })

output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

filename = function() {
  paste(name, input$filetype, sep = ".")
},

content = function(file) {
  sep <- switch(input$filetype, "csv" = ",", "tsv" = "\t")

  write.table(RE(), file, sep = sep,
              row.names = FALSE)
}
)

}

 shinyApp(ui = ui, server=server)
```

As you can see, I'd like to download the output table to a csv or excel file... I let you try the code and then try to click on the download button, it does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Debugging

When I run the code up above and attempted to download the data set, I received the following warning and error message in the [Console Pane within RStudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200404846-Working-in-the-Console).

```
Warning: Error in paste: object 'name' not found
Stack trace (innermost first):
    1: runApp
Error : object 'name' not found
```

This led me to examine the [`paste()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/paste.html) function used within the `filename` argument in [`shiny::downloadHandler()`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/downloadHandler.html). In your code, you use the object `name` without ever assigning it a value.

I replaced `name` with the text "customTable" within the `filename` argument inside of `downloadHandler()`.

```
output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

    filename = function() {
      paste( "customTable", input$filetype, sep = ".")
    },

    content = function(file) {
      sep <- switch(input$filetype, "csv" = ",", "tsv" = "\t")

      write.table(RE(), file, sep = sep,
                  row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
```

## Downloading Data in Browser

After running the `app.R` script, I clicked on the `Open in Browser` button to view the Shiny app in a new tab on Chrome. Once there, I was successfully able to download both a .csv and .tsv file after hitting the `download` button.

*Note: I'm looking for a better reason as to why this action needs to occur, but for now, I came across this relevant SO post [Shiny app: downloadHandler does not produce a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25986107/7954106).*

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I did'nt receive the error message you posted here but I've tried to run the code by replacing name with "customTable", and you're right, we can download something but not the datatable. In my session, I can download a file named "downloadData" but this is not a csv file or another classic type of file...

Comment: @Chloe_pa, I hit the `Download` button after I clicked on the `Open in Browser` button to view the Shiny app in a new tab within Chrome. I didn't try downloading the data within my RStudio Viewer tab. I was able to successfully download both a .csv and .tsv file. Can you let me know if this helps?

Comment: Yes, it helps ! Thanks for your answer. I can download the csv file correctly when I open my app in a browser. Do you know why it doesn't work when we try to do it within RStudio Viewer tab ?

Comment: @Chloe_pa, no worries glad to help! I don't know why you can't download data from the RStudio Viewer - and couldn't find an explicit reason - but did come across this relevant SO post [Shiny app: downloadHandler does not produce a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25986107/7954106).