# Read and write csv file in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to make several data sets available for download from the Shiny app. I don't wan to display them or making any other calculations. Just make them downloadable. I've created a subdirectory called data, where I placed several csv files. My current code writes just an empty csv file, and ignores the datasets.

```
ui <- fluidPage( 
 selectInput(inputId = "dataset", label = "Select a dataset",
                             choices = c("",
                                         "a",
                                         "b",
                                         "c")
                             ),
br(),
                 
                 downloadButton("downloadData", "Download") )
```

and the server side

```
server <- function( input, output, session ) {

output$sample <- renderTable( sampleData() )
  
sampleData <- reactive({
     switch(input$dataset, 
            "a"               = read.csv("/data/a.csv"),
            "b"               = read.csv("/data/a.csv"),
            "c"                = read.csv("/data/a.csv")   )

output$sample <- renderTable( sampleData() )
  
output$downloaData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function(){
      paste("sample_dataset.csv", sep = "")
    },
    
    content = function(file) {
    write.csv(sampleData(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    })
}
```

Thank you!

---

EDIT

---

Here is the second version of the code:

```
ui <- fluidPage( 
fluidRow(
                 column(6,

                 selectInput(inputId = "dataset",
                             label = "Select a sample dataset",
                             choices = c("",
                                         "a",
                                         "b",
                                         "c",
                                         "d",
                                         "e"
                             )),
                 br(),

                 downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")),

                 tableOutput('sample'),
                 )
```

SERVER:

```
server< - function( input, output, session ) { 
 output$sample <- renderTable( sampleData() )
  
  sampleData <- reactive({
        switch(input$dataset,
               "a" = read.csv("data/a.csv"),
               "b" = read.csv("data/b.csv"),
               "c" = read.csv("data/c.csv"),
               "d" = read.csv("data/d.csv"),
               "e" = read.csv("data/e.csv")
        )})
  
  output$sample <- renderTable( sampleData() )
  
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler( 
    filename = function(){
      paste("sample_dataset.csv", sep = "")
    },
    
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(sampleData(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }) 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the `/data/a.csv` path is correct? Are you using a relative or an absolute path name?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a few things in your code:

1 - you are missing `)}` closing `sampleData <- reactive`

2 - You have an extra `/`before `data` in `read.csv`

3 - `DownloadData` is missing a lower-case d in Render

```
server <- function( input, output, session ) {

output$sample <- renderTable( sampleData() )



sampleData <- reactive({
     switch(input$dataset, 
           
            "a"               = read.csv("data/a.csv"), # you had an extra / before data
            "b"               = read.csv("data/a.csv"),
            "c"                = read.csv("data/a.csv") )}) # you were missing `)}` here

output$sample <- renderTable( sampleData() )
  
output$downloadData <- downloadHandler( #Here was DownloadData misspelled
      filename = function(){
      paste("sample_dataset.csv", sep = "")
    },
    
    content = function(file) {
    write.csv(sampleData(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    })
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! However, it writes an empty csv instead of downloading my files...

Comment: There is probably another small mistake in your code. You can copy it here and I look into it.

Comment: Thank you! I've added the new code. It contains much more than the presented chunks, however the rest of the code is unrelated to this download button.

Comment: The code works fine for me. I get a file with data. There were a couple of mistakes (like missing a parenthesis), that I had to get in place in order to render the app, but this should not be the issue in your real code since you managed to download an empty .csv file. Maybe this will help you [Shiny app: downloadHandler does not produce a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984138/shiny-app-downloadhandler-does-not-produce-a-file). There are a few good answers there. Let me know when you get it working!